# Java: Create JSON object and then read JSON field name and data pairs

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a method which creates JSON object using org.json.simple.JSONObject library:

```
public JSONObject toJSONObject() {

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("field1", value1);

    if (value2!=null) {
        jsonObj.put("field2", value2);
    }

    if (value3!=null){
        jsonObj.put("field3", value3);
    }

    return jsonObj;
}
```

then I'm trying to read fields and values from that kind of created JSON object as

```
public String getJSONFieldName() {

    //...Can't figure that part...

    return fieldName;
}


public JSONObject getJSONObject() {


    //...Can't figure that part...

    return jsonObject;
}
```

so I can use it the main class with conjunction of any JSON object not knowing field names like

```
log.put(jsonObj.getJSONFieldName(), jsonObj.getJSONObject());
```

but I'm stuck on getting `getJSONFieldName()` and `getJSONObject()` code to work.

Comment: What is `JSONObject`? What library are you using?

Comment: @user1803551 `org.json.simple.JSONObject` and I have update OP